# How to set dynamically scheme attribute in s:url tag?

Tags: java, http, https, struts2

I'm trying to build some URLs using `s:url` tag using the `scheme` attribute, whose value varies dynamically on some criteria (e.g. the same URL will be built with `http` for some requests and with `https` for some others). All `s:url` in the application will be built either with `http` or `https` for a given request.

I have programmed the logic for this criteria and stored the schema to be used (`http` or `https`) as a String field in my Action, but seems I can't use expressions in the `scheme` attribute of the `s:url` tag:

When I try to render an HTML anchor using an URL built with this:

```
<s:url scheme="%{myScheme}" id="myUrl" action="MyAction" includeParams="none">
   <s:param name="someParam" value="blah"/>
</s:url>

<s:a href="%{myUrl}">click me</s:a>
```

I get:

```
<a href="%{myScheme}://myhost.com/mywebapp/MyAction.action?someParam=blah">click me</a>
```

Also tried to do an ugly thing, even without using the actual action property (if that worked, I would change the literal for the actual value). Tried to use a scriptlet:

```
<s:url scheme="<%= "https" %>" id="myUrl" action="MyAction" includeParams="none">
   <s:param name="someParam" value="blah"/>
</s:url>
```

But got a `500` error and this log message:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /path/to/my/file.jsp(123,456) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute scheme does not accept any expressions
```

I tried also with the following ugly options, which didn't work:

```
<s:url scheme="<s:property value="myScheme"/>" id="myUrl" action="MyAction" includeParams="none">
   <s:param name="someParam" value="blah"/>
</s:url>
```

and:

```
<s:url scheme="<c:out value="${myScheme}"/>" id="myUrl" action="MyAction" includeParams="none">
   <s:param name="someParam" value="blah"/>
</s:url>
```

So I ran out of ideas. Did anybody face the same problem? The remainder of the question explains why I need to do this:

My application is behind a load balancer that receives HTTPS requests, but forwards them to the application server with HTTP, and then sends the responses back with HTTPS to the internet. So the application servers always receive `HTTP` traffic.

The links in the application must be generated with https scheme when requested via the load balancer (so users in the internet will be secured) and with http when requested directly (when we developers need to access a specific front-end within our internal network). I have no control over servers configuration nor so much influence over sysadmins, so changing server or network configurations seems rather problematic.

UPDATE

Seems that if I extend the `org.apache.struts2.components.ServletUrlRenderer` Struts2 class overriding the `renderUrl` method I would be able to do what I want. But I do not know how I would tell Struts2 to use my custom implementation of `UrlRenderer` instead of the default `ServletUrlRenderer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer, as I advanced when I updated the question.

My findings are that:

- The `scheme` attribute in `s:url` tag doesn't support expressions, only literal values.
- I needed to change the default behaviour of Struts2.

So what I've done:

- Removed all `scheme` attributes in all `s:url` tags in all JSPs in my application.
- Implemented `UrlRenderer` with a custom class, using almost a copy of `ServletUrlRenderer`. I changed the line where the `renderUrl` method retrieves the default value for the scheme with: `String scheme = ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().findString("scheme");`. This sets the default value for the scheme as the "scheme" property of the current Action.
- Added the following property to `struts.properties`. This property tells Struts2 to use my custom implementation:

`struts.urlRenderer = fully.qualified.name.for.my.CustomUrlRendererImplementation`

This solution introduces maintainability issues because I copy-pasted some code from the 2.3.8 version of Struts. If there is anybody that comes with a better solution I'll be happy to test it :)

Comment: This can be a security hole in the application. It would be better to request change in the <s:url/> tag.

Comment: @LukaszLenart Thanks for your comment. I'm thinking about changing the location where the protocol to be used is stored, so any request made with a "scheme" parameter would not change the expected behaviour of the application. Anyway, I'm tied to the guidelines made by the sysadmins and CIO, so I just wanted to make sure my app generates "https" links although the architecture is not so good.

Comment: Please register an issue of <s:url/>, it's a valid use case :-) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW

Comment: One more request, could you share you implementation of UrlRenderer? I would like to check how easy/hard was to extend ServletUrlRenderer.

Comment: @LukaszLenart Will do tomorrow at ASF jira; right now I don't have access to the code. But I found some problems when I tried to extend `ServletUrlRenderer`, so in the end instead of extending that class I copied and modified it to my needs, "hacking" the package to be `org.apache.struts2.components` because of visibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

tough to figure this one...try with s:set to set the value of myscheme and use the jsp variable.